# getting *current* stack trace in node.js (via SIGINT, for example)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, signals, stack-trace

I have a very cpu-intensive application.
I wonder if it's possible to get the current stack trace in order to understand, via SIGINT termination, for example, in which specific function is the current computation.

I tried adding the following handler:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    log('SIGINT!')
    var stack = new Error().stack;
    log( stack );
    log('quitting.');
    process.exit();
});
```

but it seems that it's called only when the intensive computation is ended and not immediately as I press *Ctrl-C*.

any idea on how to follow the execution without polluting the code with log messages?

Answer (score 1):

The `--trace-sigint` option was initially introduced in [`nodejs/node#290207`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29207). It was reviewed & subsequently merged into Node's main release channel in May 2020 as part of the v12.17.0 release.

When this option is passed to the `node` runtime, any `SIGINT` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in most environments) will not only end execution of the script, but also print a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a specific answer for your issue but I would look for synchronous code (like fs.*Sync)

I suggest node-inspector (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) which allow to get a clue of what is happening either with step by step in the code and some reporting about resources usage